# Use of random in a Hangman game

Tags: python

This is a Hangman game. The fact is that the user counts with one help, which can be used to reveal one of the letters of the word. I need it for the unknown letters (actually it works randomly and when the user has the word almost done it's more probably for the letter to be revealed yet, so there's no really help)
How can I modify the code for it to reveal a letter that hasn't been revealed yet?

```
import random

#AHORCADO

lista_palabras=['programacion', 'python', 'algoritmo', 'computacion', 'antioquia', 'turing', 'ingenio', 'AYUDA']
vidas=['','','','','','','']
num_word=random.randint(0,6)
palabra=lista_palabras[num_word]

print(' _ '*len(palabra))
print('Inicias con siete vidas', "".join(vidas),'\n', 'Pista: escribe AYUDA para revelar una letra (sólo tienes disponible 1)')
#print(palabra)

palabra_actual=['_ ']*len(palabra)
posicion=7
contador_pistas=0



while True:
 fullword="".join(palabra_actual)

#condición para ganar
 if letra==palabra or fullword==palabra:
   print(palabra)
   print('¡GANASTE!')
   break
 letra=input('Inserta una letra: ')

#condición que agrega letra adivinada
 if letra in palabra:
   orden=[i for i in range(len(palabra)) if palabra[i] == letra]
   for letras in orden:
     palabra_actual[letras]=letra
   print(''.join(palabra_actual))

#condición AYUDAs
 elif letra=='AYUDA' and contador_pistas==0:
   pista=random.randint(0,len(palabra)-1)
   palabra_actual[pista]=palabra[pista]
   print(''.join(palabra_actual))
   contador_pistas+=1

#condición límite de ayudas
 elif letra=='AYUDA' and contador_pistas>=1:
   print('Ya no te quedan pistas restantes')

#condición para perder
 elif letra not in lista_palabras:
   posicion-=1
   vidas[posicion]=''
   print('¡Perdiste una vida!',''.join(vidas))
   if posicion==0:
     print('GAME OVER')
     break
```

Thank you <3

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of of index values for the word, and remove the indexes from the list as the user selects the correct characters. then when they ask for help, you can call `random.choice` on the remaining indexes so you are guarateed to get one that hasn't been chosen yet

```
...
...

palabra_actual=['_ ']*len(palabra)
posicion=7
contador_pistas=0
indexes = list(range(len(palabra)))  # list of index values


while True:
 fullword="".join(palabra_actual)

 if letra==palabra or fullword==palabra:
   print(palabra)
   print('¡GANASTE!')
   break
 letra=input('Inserta una letra: ')

 if letra in palabra:
   orden=[i for i in range(len(palabra)) if palabra[i] == letra]
   for letras in orden:
     indexes.remove(letras)  # remove index values for selected characters
     palabra_actual[letras]=letra
   print(''.join(palabra_actual))

 elif letra=='AYUDA' and contador_pistas==0:
   pista=random.choice(indexes)    # choose from remaining index values using random.choice
   palabra_actual[pista]=palabra[pista]
   print(''.join(palabra_actual))
   contador_pistas+=1

...
...
```